# How to fix Feature with Panels

Tags: panels, features

I am managing a website that makes extensive use of panels. I had a "system" panel page with Title = 'Registration Template' and a path of 'registration/%registration'.

Somehow, in updating the features on the LIVE site, I managed to loose this panel page. It is not available on the LIVE site. I can recreate a feature with "registration_view_panel_context" this under Page Manager.

But when I move this feature to the live site, it does not become available to me as a panel. It is included in the feature, but the feature is overridden. I am unable to "revert" the feature.

- Despite being labeled as a "system" page, the 'Registration Template' is not available to me.
- As a "system" page, I do not have the option of exporting it from my local site.
- And when I try to revert the feature on LIVE - nothing happens.
- If I try to create a new panel page on LIVE with this path - "registration/%registration" I get a message "that path is already in use. This system cannot override existing paths."

This panel page is still available to me and works on my local site, but I can't figure out how to move it back onto the LIVE site.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Solved this problem myself (not myself, but with local help :-) 
See below for answer.

Comment: It turns out I needed to recreate this "system" page as an "existing page" using the - Page Manager Existing Pages - module (https://www.drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages). I am not entirely sure why, but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to recreate this "system" page as an "existing page" using the - Page Manager Existing Pages - module (drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages). I am not entirely sure why, but this solved my problem.